# Jira Rest API Calls in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, jira, azure-data-factory, jira-rest-api

Good Day

I configured a Pipeline Copy Data job in Azure Data Factory to extract data from Jira with an API call using the rest API connector in Azure.

1. When i configure and test the connection it is successful.

[image]

2. Now when i try to preview the data in the Copy container i get the following error.

[image]

Does anyone know what this error means and how do i bypass it?

I believe i am not the first one trying to extract data from Jira via Rest API.

Thank you and Regards

Rayno

Answer (score 0):

> Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file ".Check if the data
>   is in valid JSON object format.Unexpected character encountered while
>   parsing value:<.Path".....

I think the error already indicates the root cause.You data format is invalid JSON format,you could try to simulate rest api invoke to make sure if the situation exists.ADF can't help you handle the illegal deserialization.

In addition,according to the connector [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-jira),ADF supports `JIRA connector`.Maybe you could try to have a try on that.

Comment: Hi Jay, i used postman to call the API and the return worked fine, like you mentioned i guess it is and ADF specific limitation where ADF does not allow the illegal format. I will go ahead and try the official Jira connector, but will keep this post open for now if i have more questions. Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't already, put in a nicely worded ticket to jira.atlassian.com. They usually aren't fast enough to solve the problem as you would wish, but maybe they will solve it in time for the next person to try this.

Comment: Thanks Keynan, it seems like raising it with Atlassian is the only option we have at this stage.

Comment: Thanks Keynan, it seems like raising it with Atlassian is the only option we have at this stage. I have opened a ticket with Microsoft support and Atlassian, will advise as soon as i get feedback from them.